# CSS (maybe Jquery too) does not work properly on page's first load (in IE)

Tags: jquery, css, cycle

I am using IE 8.

If you go to http://site2.ewart.library.ubc.ca/, you will find the text below the (carousel) image is aligned to the right, while it is supposed to aligned to the center.

However, if you click the left & right button to navigate the carousel, the text will be aligned to the center.

I guess it might be some jquery (and its cycle plug-in) issue. But I am not sure.

Also, the left & right buttons are not aligned corrected. It should be on the right of the dots. It works in FF but not in IE.

Comment: Looks fine to me in IE8 - it's initially centered as is desired. There are, however, two other issues: `spacer.gif` returns `404 not found`, and your `jquery.cycle.all` seems to be being transferred as binary as opposed to script.

Comment: It is weird. It does not work on my desktop (IE8) and laptop (IE 7).

Comment: Thanks. When it is transferred as binary? 
    <script src="http://github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/jquery.cycle.all.latest.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>

Answer (score 0):

It looks correct to me in IE8. The left and right arrows are to the right of the dots and everything is center aligned. I am using IE8 also.